# Change value of global variable, C

Tags: c, global-variables

So I'm trying to find a way to update a variable and I've tried to make it global so I can change it easily. The only problem is it isn't working and i don't know how to fix it.

I want SIZE_ARRAY to change to the value it becomes every time I call the remove_unimportant_words function.

**Decleration:**

```
int SIZE_ARRAY = 480; 
char list[SIZE_ARRAY][MAX];
void remove_unimportant_words(char word[MAX],  int SIZE_ARRAY, char list[SIZE_ARRAY][MAX] , int j, int i);
```

**int main():**

```
while (fscanf(file, "%s", word) != EOF){
      remove_unimportant_words(word, SIZE_ARRAY, list,  j,  i);
      }
```

**Function:**

```
void remove_unimportant_words(char word[MAX], int SIZE_ARRAY, char list[SIZE_ARRAY][MAX] , int j, int i)
{

    for (i=0; i<SIZE_ARRAY; i++) {
        if(strcmp(list[i],word) == 0){
            for (j=i; j<SIZE_ARRAY; j++) {
                strcpy(list[j], list[j+1]);
            }
            SIZE_ARRAY--;
            i--;
        }

    }
    printf("%d\n", SIZE_ARRAY);
}
```

I've basically tried printing the value of SIZE_ARRAY and it always starts at 480 when going in the function.

Comment: can you please explain this `void remove_unimportant_words(char word[MAX],  int SIZE_ARRAY, char list[SIZE_ARRAY][MAX] , int j, int i);`?

Comment: The `SIZE_ARRAY` in your `remove_unimportant_words` function is a completely independent variable; modifying it will not modify the global variable.

Comment: You are passing a copy of `SIZE_ARRAY` rather the global SIZE_ARRAY variable itself. Either pass a reference/pointer to SIZE_ARRAY or access it directly from within the function.

Comment: Another way of dealing with it is to declare the function as int and then return any new value of `SIZE_ARRAY` which you then assign to the global. `SIZE_ARRAY = remove_unimportant_words(char word[MAX], int SIZE_ARRAY, char list[SIZE_ARRAY][MAX] , int j, int i);`

Comment: We seem to be getting ahead of ourselves here. The first two lines that you posted `int SIZE_ARRAY = 480; char list[SIZE_ARRAY][MAX];` won't even compile.

Answer (score 1):

As you are passing **SIZE_ARRAY** as parameter in your function `remove_unimportant_words`, This is not using as global in that function any more.. So Global **SIZE_ARRAY** remains same.

You should not pass **SIZE_ARRAY** as parameter. Hope your code will work as expected.

```
void remove_unimportant_words(char word[MAX],  char list[SIZE_ARRAY][MAX] , int j, int i)
{

...
```

Answer (score 1):

If `SIZE_ARRAY` is a global variable as you stated, you need not pass another integer parameter to the function `remove_unimportant_words()`.

The `SIZE_ARRAY` you passed into remove_unimportant_words() effectively shadows the global variable with a local copy of a **unrelated, newly allocated variable** also under the name `SIZE_ARRAY` which will be deallocated as the function returns.

In essence:

```
void remove_unimportant_words(char word[MAX], int SIZE_ARRAY, char list[SIZE_ARRAY][MAX] , int j, int i);
```

the `int SIZE_ARRAY` parameter there shows no relation to the actual global SIZE_ARRAY variable and should be removed as so that code within the function body references the global `SIZE_ARRAY` variable directly.

You could potentially also use addresses and pointers to pass the variable by reference if you mean to merely pass `SIZE_ARRAY` from one function to another.

As a side note, are you sure the code you provided compiles? I see a lot of syntax that doesn't seem valid...

Answer (score 0):

Just do not use `SIZE_ARRAY` as a parameter, function `remove_unimportant_words` can access it just as usual